# Como saber se uma Image View já tem alguma imagem?

Tags: ios

Como saber se uma  Image View já tem alguma imagem ?

Answer (score 4):

```
UIImage *imagem = [[UIImage alloc] init];

if (imagem.image != nil)
   // imagem existe
else
   // imagem não existe
```